# Table sorting with calculated value in a column cell with angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I was wondering how I can sort a table on a column cell that has been calculated.

For example, in the table below, how would I sort the TCD column so that the lowest value is displayed at the top of the table? As there is a calculation in the cell I'm not sure how to do it.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
<th>MD</th>
<th>TCD</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr  ng-repeat="product in selectedProductPrices">
    <td>£{{ product.RecurringCost  | number:2}}</td>
    <td>£{{ product.OneOffCost + product.OneOffCostMargin + ((product.RecurringCost + product.RecurringCostMargin) * productAttributesObj.Term) | number:2}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need custom orderBy 
Example

```
<tr  ng-repeat="product in selectedProductPrices|orderBy:myValueFunction">
```

In controller:-

```
$scope.myValueFunction = function(product) {
   return product.OneOffCost + product.OneOffCostMargin + ((product.RecurringCost + product.RecurringCostMargin) * productAttributesObj.Term);
};
```